# Why does GCC emit unnecessary dynamic initialization code for unused inline variables?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, code-size, inline-variable

When defining `inline` variables in `.cpp` source file, for example by including a header, gcc generates code for guards + initialization of the variables in each `.cpp` source. Even if the variables are not used anywhere in the `.cpp`.
Instructions generated by clang are not as clear whether there is the same overhead.
[Compile Explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/ePvYTajqq).

The overhead results in significant code size increase (with multiple variables in heavily used header), which may be important for embedded development. Using `extern` does not have the same penalty, but requires definition in a separate source file.

Questions:

- Is this the expected behavior?
- Does clang behave the same, but hidden?
- Can this be avoided while  still using `inline` and not `extern`?

Comment: Do these variables need to be modifiable?  If not making them constexpr should remove the overhead

Comment: Many embedded primitives require casts from uint to pointers, resulting in `reinterpret_cast`s and preventing the constructors from being `constexpr`. Shifting the casts from constructors to access methods would require a significant rewrite, possibly approaching the complexity of writing Hardware Abstraction Layer from scratch.